# Where clause in EF

Tags: entity-framework

we have 4 entities:

- `Bills`
- `BillDetails`
- `Products`
- `ProductGroups`

what I want to do is something like this

```
var qry = from bill in ctx.Bills
          join billDetail in ctx.BillDetails on bill.Id equal billDetail.Bill_Id
          join product in ctx.Products on billDetail.Product_Id equals product.Id
          join productGroup in ctx.ProductGroups 
                               on product.ProductGroup_Id equals productGroup.Id
          where 
               productGroup.Id == 113
          select bill;
```

The problem is if we disable lazy loading the returned `bill` dos not contains `BillDetail` entity,
we have to return it explicitly as anonymous object.

Is there any way to convert it to something like this ?

```
var qry = ctx.Bills
          .Include("BillDetails.Products.ProductGroup")
          .where(s=>s.BillDetails.Products.ProductGroup.Id == 113);
```

Comment: Sid note - you can simply do `Include("BillDetails.Products.ProductGroup")` - it will include `BillDetails` and `BillDetails.Products` as well

Comment: the main problem is in where condition not in how to use include ^_^

Comment: we cant put this phares inside where 's=>s.BillDetails.Products.ProductGroup.Id == 113'

Comment: Edited ! tnx for Sid Note XD

Comment: @jbutler483 side note - [Sid](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0004523/?ref_=tt_cl_t2) is happy)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you need, but something like this may work:

```
var qry = ctx.Bills
      .Include("BillDetails.Products.ProductGroup")
      .SelectMany(b => b.BillDetails)
      .Where(bd => bd.Product.ProductGroup.Id == 113);
```

Comment: got an error on 2nd SelectMany method  X(( , The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: How about now? It's tough to figure out the exact syntax without seeing your complete model.

Comment: by the way , when we use SelectMany(b => b.BillDetails) the result is collection of IEnumreable<BillDetails> but what i need is Bill Itself

Comment: i asked this before at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989601/add-the-where-clause-dynamically-in-nested-collections-of-an-entity